# Building in model callback returning nil for value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

First, thanks for taking the time to read. I'm new to Rails and have been stuck on this one for many hours.

In my Rails 3.2 app, I have three models: User, Organization, and Membership (the last is a join model between User and Organization).

When a user creates an organization, he/she should become a member upon create. So, in my Organization model, I've included a before_create callback that builds a Membership. **The problem is that while the Membership builds when the new Organization is created, the user_id on the Membership object is set to "nil.,"** and therefore the current user is not a member.

Hardcoding in the user_id attribute in the callback actually does correctly build the membership, i.e. `(:user_id => "1")`, but in general asking the Organization model to be aware of current user state seems like bad MVC practice.

**What's the proper way to set the current user ID on the new Membership?** It seems like my associations should handle that, but I might be wrong.

Here are my models — I'm leaving out some validation lines for readability's sake. Thanks so much in advance.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :organizations, :through => :memberships
end
```

**membership.rb**

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :organization
end
```

**organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :memberships
    has_many :users, :through => :memberships
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :memberships, :allow_destroy => true
    ...
    before_create :add_membership

    protected
    def add_membership
        self.memberships.build
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in the fact that allowing your model to magically know about the current user is bad MVC practice. So you have to somehow pass the current user id during creation. you can do this in many ways ; for example in the controller :

```
def create 
  @organization = Organization.new( params[:organization] ) do |org|
    org.memberships.build( user_id: current_user.id )
  end
  # save, etc.
end
```

Doing this in the controller is fine, but it would be better if your business logic would reflect the fact that a user creating an organization should automatically belong to it. You could override `new` and / or `create` on `Organization` (or create your own method if you fear overrides) :

```
def new( params = {}, options = {} )
  creator = options.delete( :creator )
  super( params, options ) do |org|
    org.memberships.build( user_id: creator.id ) if creator
    yield org if block_given?
  end
end
```

passing the user is easy now :

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(params[:organization], creator: current_user)
end
```

If you don't like this approach, or if you don't want to override `new` or create a specific factory method, you can also make something similar to `nested_attributes` :

```
attr_accessible :creator_id

def creator_id=( user_id )
  memberships.build user_id: user_id
end
```

then in your view :

```
f.hidden_field :creator_id, current_user.id
```

**optional** :

with first approach, for additional clarity / ease of use, you can also create a method on `User` :

```
def new_organization( params = {}, options = {}, &block )
  Organization.new( params, options.merge(creator: self), &block )
end
```

... ok, `Organization` is hardcoded here (bad !) but your workflow is now quite understandable :

```
def create
  # we know at first glance that the user is responsible for the organization
  # creation, and that there must be specific logic associated to this
  @organization = current_user.new_organization( params[:organization] )
  # etc
end
```

with a little more thinking, it should be possible to avoid hardcoding `Organization` into `User` (using an association extension for instance)

**EDIT**

To be able to setup a validation on membership's organization presence, you need to do this :

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, inverse_of: :organization
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :memberships

  validates :organization, presence: true
end
```

Let's explain this :

- `inverse_of` sets up your associations to be bidirectional. By default, associations are one-way, which means that when you do `organization.memberships.first.organization`, rails tries to load the organisation again because it does not know how to "climb back" the association. When using `inverse_of`, rails knows it does not have to reload the organization.
- `validates` MUST be setup on `organization` and NOT on `organization_id`. This way the validator knows we're "climbing back" the association, it knows that `organization` is a "parent" record and that it's in the process of being saved - so it does not complain.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is helpful and I'm learning quite a bit. The first solution isn't passing validation because the `organization_id` for `Membership` is blank. I assume it's because the Organization hasn't been created yet? I'm still working through the other solutions. Thanks again.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to remove that validation, and still have it create correctly.

Comment: this is a common problem with nested_attributes : you want to validate presence of parent record, but parent record does not exist yet... there's a workaround, i'll edit my answer to show you how to do

Comment: Super interesting. I never knew of inverse_of. Thanks again!